# RxJS map array with another observables and return array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, ecmascript-6

I have array of options that is coming from server

```
const options = [
  {key: 1, label: 'label1'},
  {key: 2, label: 'label2'},
  {key: 3, label: 'label3'},
  {key: 4, label: 'label4'},
  {key: 5, label: 'label5'},
  {key: 6, label: 'label6'},
];
```

what I need is to map each array item with translation based on its `key` and return array of translated options

```
const options = [
  {key: "key1", label: 'label1', translated: 'translation 1'},
  {key: "key2", label: 'label2', translated: 'translation 2'},
  {key: "key3", label: 'label3', translated: 'translation 3'},
  {key: "key4", label: 'label4', translated: 'translation 4'},
  {key: "key5", label: 'label5', translated: 'translation 5'},
  {key: "key6", label: 'label6', translated: 'translation 6'},
];
```

I managed to do this using `from(options)` but it obviously emits each member of array separatelly - I need full array instead. In the code below I'm tryingtried to zip all translations, but I receive array of translated strings only - how do I map them back into each `option`?

```
import { of, from, timer, zip } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const getTranslation = (key) => of('translation ' + key)

const options = [
  { key: "key1", label: 'label1' },
  { key: "key2", label: 'label2' },
  { key: "key3", label: 'label3' },
  { key: "key4", label: 'label4' },
  { key: "key5", label: 'label5' },
  { key: "key6", label: 'label6' },
];

of(options).pipe(
  mergeMap(options =>
    zip(...options.map(option =>
      getTranslation(option.key)))
  )).subscribe(console.log);
```

here I created [playground on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5agh72?devtoolsheight=60)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map each option to an Observable and then forkJoin them all:

```js
forkJoin(options.map(options =>
  getTranslation(option.key).pipe(map(translation => ({
    ...option,
    translated: translation
  })))
)).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: yeah this works even with `mapMerge` - the key to solving was passing `getTranslation()` result to `pipe(map(translation => {...}))`, tyvm!

Answer (score -1):

Use spread and rest (`...`) to collect and then re-spread the rest of the object:

```
zip(...options.map(({ key, ...option }) => ({ ...option, key: getTranslation(key) })))
```

Comment: this will pass multiple `{...option, key: getTranslatedKey()}` objects  while `zip` expects multiple Observables as input